# line break in enumeration and \underline command

Tags: line-breaking

How can I break a line that is inside of an enumeration, and \underline{} command, without using \usepackage{soul} and it's \ul{} command?

```
\item{\textbf{\underline{Long string of text that needs to be broken.}}}
```

I need it to break mid way through. e.g.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
\item{\textbf{\underline{This is a long string\\ that I want to break}}}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Comment: `\underline` uses an `\hbox`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`\underline` can’t be broken across lines, thats why `soul` exists … if you need a break you have to split the command manually.

```
\item \textbf{\underline{This is a long string} \\
      \underline{that I want to break}}
```

I strongly recommend **not** to use underlines, though!

Furthermore you may note that `\item` doesn’t have an argument …

Answer (score 0):

Solution for my problem:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
\item{\textbf{\underline{This is a long string}}}\\
\textbf{\underline{ that I want to break}}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Split the line manually, add a `\\` to the end. Then wrap the end of the line in the same commands without the `\item{}`